# How to disable Google Drive for a service account while keeping the Drive API enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I'm trying to disable Google Drive for a service account in Google Cloud while keeping the Drive API enabled so that the service account can still use it to access files and shared resources.

I have tried following some steps, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Currently, the service account's personal drive is enabled along with the Drive API. I would like to disable the personal drive but retain access through the Drive API.

I have checked Google Cloud's documentation, but I couldn't find specific instructions for this use case. I have also looked into IAM permissions and didn't find a specific role to disable only the personal drive.

Could someone provide guidance on how to disable Google Drive for a service account while keeping the Drive API enabled?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: You simply can't. However, if a service account can't access Google Drive resources, there is no problem to let him the API permission, it will be able to do anything